# Added additional pay-as-you-go subscription, many VM sizes unavailable

Tags: azure, subscription

I recently created and renamed an additional pay-as-you-go subscription in order to segregate billing by site.  Now, however, when I try to create a VM the majority of the sizes no longer seem to be available. I have tried changing regions, no change.  What might be the cause for this?

[image]

Comment: The image was Server 2016 Core Datacenter (smalldisk) though I also tried the non-core cersion and the non-smalldisk version with the same results.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I had an MSDN subscription which allowed me access to all VM sizes, but when I created a new subscription there was a very limited set of VM sizes available to me.  This was due to Capacity Management restrictions.

I raised a Subscription support ticket with Microsoft (subscription support is free, no need to purchase a support plan) and they are in the process of lifting the restrictions.

Include in the support ticket what VM sizes, number of cores, Azure region, subscription GUID and amount of storage in TB you will want to use - these are the first things they asked me.